# add image in Jpanel using canvas

Tags: java, swing, canvas, netbeans, jpanel

i want to add image to my panel which is created by Netbeans GUI Designer. 
here's my canvas class

```
private static class GraphicsClass extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Toolkit tkit;
        tkit=getToolkit();
        Image img=tkit.getImage("ampera.jpg");
        g.drawImage(img,0,0,this);
    }
}
```

and this is how i use it in JFrame class constructor

```
this.Jpanel1=new GraphicsClass();
```

but the image doesnt show. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.Jpanel1=new GraphicsClass();
```

Won't work. Assuming you just drag and dropped a panel onto the frame and named it `Jpanel1`, then in the constructor you did the above code. When you first drag and drop the original panel, it gets initialized and laid out. When you do the above code, you are making a new component. The original panel is still the one added, and is *not* the same referenced panel and the new one you just created. So the new panel will never show, it is just the one (with no reference identifier). Like if you has something like

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    public MyFrame() {
        initComponents();
        jPanel1 = new GraphicsClass();
    }

    private void initComponent() {
        jPanel1 = new JPanel();
        // add jPanel1 to frame
    }

    private class GraphicsClass extends JPanel {}

    private JPanel jpanel1;
}
```

That's the basic netbeans setup. The code in the `initComponents` method is autogenerated and is not editable by default. You *could* edit it, but I would advise against it (unless you really know what you're doing). If you look at the code, you will see exactly what I wan talking about in the beginning.

Fix: Created a panel form from the designer (i.e. New->Swing Form->JPanel form). Then you can simply drag and drop the panel to the frame, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22194357/2587435)

**Other note:**

- Don't create your images in the `paintComponent` method. Make it a class member and create it in the constructor.
- Instead of a panel, if you want to create an image (say for a background), you can use an `ImageIcon` and a `JLabel` and set the layout manager to the label, You can then start adding component onto the label.

  1. Drag and drop an label
  2. Go to the properties of the label and click the <kbd>...</kbd> of the `icon` property. In the dialog, you can browse for an image.
  3. Then right click the label from the design view, and set a layout manager for the label. You can then start adding components to the label.

Comment: Thanks it really works :D , but it doesnt works in JDK 8,it showing unsupported major.minor version 52.0  so i change my project to JDK 7, i'm using OpenJDK. Thanks man :D

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by using the BufferedImage class, or using the MediaTracker to track when your image has loaded

Comment: i use this example http://pastebin.com/sLavqRPK , and i modify paintComponent() function as like my code above, and the image loaded correctly, but i dont know how to use this code to my JPanel which is created by Netbeans Builder

Comment: In NetBeans, select your Jpanel, go properties palette, go code, go custom creation code

Comment: JPanel, by extension, is a ImageConsumer, there by passing "this" to drawImage, it will take care of scheduling repaints as required.